# Javascript ".attr" not work on ie11 and optimization questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, countdowntimer

It works fine with the following JavaScript.

However, I do not know how to check if there is a "data-end-date" value when loading for the first time.

It is a JavaScript that counts down with an end-date value.

For example:
(Actually li is exposed as a for statement)

```
<ul>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date="2019-01-25 14:00:00"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date=""></div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date="2019-01-27 14:00:00"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date=""></div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date="2019-01-29 14:00:00"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="time-wrap" class="time-countdown" data-end-date="2019-01-29 14:00:00"></div>
</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

```
$('.time-countdown').each(function(i){
        var timeSaleWrap = $(this);
        var serialDate = timeSaleWrap.data('end-date');//data value
        var endDate = new Date(serialDate); 

        timeSaleWrap.attr('id', "time-wrap" + (i + 1));
        Timesalescounter(endDate, 'time-wrap' + (i + 1));

        function Timesalescounter(dt, id) {

            var endTime = new Date(dt);
            var slaeEnd = endTime.getTime(dt);
            var evEdate = slaeEnd;

            var timer;


            function actuionWrap() {

            var startTime = new Date();
            var today = startTime.getTime();
            var evSdate = today;
            var deltaTime = evEdate - evSdate;

            var s = Math.floor(deltaTime / 1000);
            var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
            var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
            var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

            h %= 24;
            m %= 60;
            s %= 60;

            var weeks = Math.floor(d / 7);
            var d = d - weeks * 2;

            var timeS = Math.floor( evSdate / 1000 );
            var timeE = Math.floor( evEdate / 1000 );
            var timeT = Math.floor( timeE - timeS );

                if ( !timeT || timeT < 0 ) {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = "00h";
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = "00m";
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = "00s";

                    return;
                } else {

                    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
                    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
                    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

                    var time_content= "<div class='clock-wrap'>"+
                        "<div class='days cell' title='Days'>"+d+"<span id='sp_days'>days</span></div>"+
                        "<div class='hours cell' title='Hours'>"+h+"<span id='sp_hours'>hours</span></div>"+
                        "<div class='mins cell' title='Minutes'>"+m+"<span id='sp_minutes'>mins</span></div>"+
                        "<div class='secs cell' title='Seconds'>"+s+"<span id='sp_seconds'>secs</span></div>"+
                        "</div>";

                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = time_content;


                }

            } //actuionWrap

            timer = setInterval(actuionWrap, 1000);

        }
    });
```

There are now 5 examples, but in practice there may be more than 100.

This JavaScript seems to take a long time to load the first time the page loads.

Is there a value for "data-end-date" and I do not have to check for it?

Or would it be slower if I had a "data-end-date" value and checked for nothing?

How do you optimize it?

Add:
Why does not it work in IE11? No error / error is displayed.

```
timeSaleWrap.attr('id', "timesale-wrap" + (i + 1));
```

It does not work.

Comment: None of what you're doing there looks expensive. Even if there were 100 items, it shouldn't take any real CPU time at all, I would think. I can see *some* optimizations that could be made, but I'm doubtful the code here is what's causing the laggyness you're experiencing. (though I notice you're only calling the `actuionWrap` in the interval, do you also want to call it immediately?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want to make an immediate call. I do not want the load time to increase.

Comment: Ok, then call the function immediately in addition to the `setInterval`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok. actuionWrap(); timer = setInterval(actuionWrap, 1000); Also, does calling the function with setInterval instantly optimize the JavaScript?

Comment: "Optimize"? No, but it does what you want, otherwise `actuionWrap` won't be called for another second

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Thank you so much for this! I just have one question. Can not optimize the JavaScript in question? :(

Comment: Yes, there are a number of things you could do to make the code more elegant and to reduce processing/rendering time, feel free to improve it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wonder how to do that.I want to reduce processing / rendering time.Can you tell me how?  :(

Comment: Try this $('.time-countdown').each(function(i,timeSaleWrap){.... instead of this ......$('.time-countdown').each(function(i){....

Comment: @kewlashu Thank you for your comment.It works correctly. Thank you!